# Why did General Pryde describe "Kijimi" as a settlement instead of place?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

> KYLO REN: Report, General Pryde.
>
> General Pryde: There's been a development, sir. The Knights of Ren
>   have tracked the scavenger. **To a settlement called Kijimi**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can assume that General Pryde is merely repeating verbatim what the Knights of Ren reported to him.

> “Sir,” Allegiant General Pryde said. “The Knights of Ren have tracked the scavenger.”
>
> Ren’s stride hitched.
>
> “To a settlement called Kijimi,” Admiral Griss added.
>
> “They’re searching there now,” Pryde said.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Rise of Skywalker: Expanded Edition](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Rise_of_Skywalker:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

As to why they've identified it as a "*settlement*", that would presumably be to explain that their quarry is in a place with people and that they're ***concealing themselves amongst the population*** rather than that they're just hiding out on a rock somewhere. Also calling it a settlement (as opposed to "a city" or "a town") helps to describe the size of the place and the general environment that they're working with (sprawling, messy, populous, unruly) and hence the amount of time it'll likely take to find them.

Comment: Kijimi is the planet with Kijimi City on it. It’s entirely plausible to call the city just Kijimi and it makes sense as is.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - I'm assuming Pryde has never heard of Kijimi (either as a 'city/settlement' or even the planet).It's just a speck of dirt on his big star map

Comment: Sure just saying there’s rationale to it even if he had done.